# How can I unit test the method having else condition?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am new to unit testing. I want to test a method which uploads a profile picture for the user. I want to know how can I test **else path** in the following method:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("profilePicture")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpsertUserProfilePictureAsync([FromForm]IFormFile file)
{
    var postedFile = Request.Form.Files.FirstOrDefault();
    if (user.ProfilePictureUrl == null)
    {
        await _contentUploadService.UploadProfilePictureAsync(postedFile.ContentType, user, postedFile.OpenReadStream());
    }
    else
    {
        var existingImageUrl = user.ProfilePictureUrl;
        await _contentUploadService.UploadProfilePictureAsync(postedFile.ContentType, user, postedFile.OpenReadStream());
        var blob = new CloudBlockBlob(new Uri(existingImageUrl), _storageCredentials);
        await blob.DeleteAsync();
    }
    return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status204NoContent);
}
```

I am using a mock file but I don't know how to check **else part** of the file. Can any body help me in this case...

Comment: Are you aware of mocking?

Comment: In this method you only can test the Return Code. You can mock both update method, but are only mocks not test.

Comment: @Sweeper Not fully but have an introduction of it.

Comment: @Sweeper I want to know if the method works fine if there is existing profile picture. I want to write unit test for existing profile picture

Comment: as @AntonioMiguelRomanGodinez pointed you can unit test only the result, if you want to test if it works correctly - you need to make an integration test.

Comment: Maybe, if you use Fake instead of Mock, you can write some workaround to check it out, any way as @Dimitar says, you need an integration test, not unit.

Comment: Mocl the dependencies, then you can test the behavior of this method. Ideally you shouldn't have much logic in this method at all but that would just move your code somewhere else, you would have the same problems testing that other location though you might not have to contend with http request mocks. The best advice is to start using dependency injection and mocks.

Comment: @AntonioMiguelRomanGodinez Sorry if I am asking for too much. How can I test the result in this case.

Comment: @SajadAhanger the problem is you have some strong dependencies as user Object and CloudBlockBlob class, first of all you must think to improve your method to another easier to test. For example, should extract de CloudBlockBlob action to a service that can mock in the Test and ¿where user come from?.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to never use `if...else` in unit tests. Split your unit tests into two:

1. Test with Null value
2. Test with Non null value

You might not want to test your Unit test with logical units in it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider first extracting an interface, forexample of IUser with Resharper or similar too get the following example code.

```
public interface IUser {
 string UserName { get; set; }
 }
```

Great, so now we can define the variable user as being an IUser instead.

```
IUser user = GetUser();
```

Now, you need to change User to implement IUser, if that is not possible, the code you test are **strongly coupled** to User. In general, try to avoid concrete types and static calls. This makes yourcode hard to test!

If you can make the transition to IUser, the road ahead is easy. Do the following Nuget command in your test project:

> Install-Package Moq

Now you can mock your user, say.

```
var userMock = new Mock<IUser>();
```

Working with interfaces and mocks makes your code so more testable and you can solve code coverage scenarios uch ss this. If User is a concrete type though, and you cannot change it to say implement IUser, you must create two unit tests for each concrete scenario.

Please believe in the following statements:

- shun static calls in your code, they are evil against testability
- stick to interfaces, not concrete types as much as possibl
- use a mocking framework such as Moq
- choose the right level of granularity and test your system under test. Do not test too many components at once
- use dependency injection and pass interfaces into constructos as dependencies.
- we want loose coupling and high cohesion
- we want testability
- we want to stick to SOLID principles